# Cannot get typeahead-on-select working with Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

See Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hsxYC2KPsf7S3non34Cy.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="result" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in cities($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item)">
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.cities = function(cityName) {
    $scope.city = cityName.split(" ");
       // $timeout emulates an async call to a server.
       return $timeout(function() {
            switch ($scope.city[0]) {
                case 'N':
                    return {cand: ["New"]};
                case 'New':
                    return {cand: ["New Albany", "New York"]};
                default:
                    return {cand: ["<no match>"]};
            }
        }, 1000).then(function(res) {
            return res.cand;
        });
  };

  $scope.onSelect = function($item) {
      $scope.cities($item);
  };
```

Give 'N' as input, wait for 1 sec. The typehead list appears, select 'New' (State A).  The list disappears, no new proposals. Press space, still no typeahead list.

Demonstration of the needed behaviour: Give 'New' as input. The typeahead list appears with 'New Albany' and 'New York' to select from. I want to see the same list in State A.

On typeahead-on-select with a true server, I am able to get the server to send the new list ('New Albany' and 'New York'), but the problem is that Angular just does not display the list.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling, it looks like you need to **set** the **$viewValue** explicitly and let angular render it for you as it normally does like so:

```
$scope.onSelect = function($item) {
   var theInput = angular.element(document.querySelector('#theInput'));
    var ngModelCtrl = theInput.controller('ngModel');

    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($item);
    ngModelCtrl.$render();
};
```

This code could probably be improved quite a bit - currently, I'm having trouble getting the dropdown to STOP displaying. But it does what you want.

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cYK6d3?p=preview).

Comment: Yes, it does, what I wanted - except that seeing that now in action, a tweak is required (to stop the dropdown displaying all the time). Something like hiding the `.dropdown-menu` before `$render()`, and then showing it again, if the user edits the input (adds a space). What would be the easiest (the most angularish) way to do that?

Comment: I'm out of time to sort this last bit out, sorry. You might want to ask another question for that.